# Custom 404 page when using Rack:Sstatic

Tags: ruby, rack

I am using Rack to build a static site and my `config.ru`file looks like this:

```
use Rack::Static,
  :urls => [""],
  :root => "public",
  :index => "index.html"

run lambda { |env|
  [
    404,
    { 'Content-Type'  => 'text/html' },
    File.open('public/404.html', File::RDONLY)
  ]
}
```

I would expect that, in the case I file would not be found, the default handler would be invoked and I would get my custom `public/404.html' error page. This is not the case. Maybe I didn't understand the docs, or I am missing something.